# Why isnt NumOfYears and Salary not being defined?

Tags: python, class

Hello i've been working on this code for a while it was working fine but then I kept getting errors and every time i fix one a new one occurs what am I not defining correctly, I already fixed the errors in the first 10 lines of code but there seems to be something im overlooking especially after line 60, added class part of code for more clarification,

```
  

 class Employee:
   count = 0

   def _init_(self, ID, name, numOfyears, salary):
       self.ID = ID
       self.Name = name
       self.NumOfYears = numOfyears
       self.Salary = salary
       Employee.count = Employee.count + 1


   def getID(self):
       return self.ID
   def getName(self):
       return self.Name
   def getnumOfyears(self):
       return self.NumOfYears
   def getSalary(self):
       return self.Salary


   def totalSalary(self):
       salary=0
       for n in range (1,5):
           if int(NumOfYears) >= 4:
               salary = (float(self.Salary) +salary)
               totalsalary=salary*0.05
       print(totalsalary,"total salary")

   def whoishighestTotalSalary(self):
       max=0
       for i in range(1,5):
           salary=int(input("enter your salary: "))
           if salary>max:
               max=salary
       print("max",max)

   def whoislowestTotalSalary(self):
       min=1000
       for i in range(1,5):
           salary=int(input("enter your salary: "))
           if salary<min:
               min=salary
       print("min",min)

   def sortEmployeeBySalary(self):
       self.employees.sort(key=lambda e: e.salary)
       print("After sorting employees by salary employees list: ")
       for e in self.employees:
           print(e)

   def printall(self):
       print(self.Name,self.ID,self.Salary,self.NumOfYears)


list=[]
for i in range(1,5):
   ID=input("ID: ")
   Name=input("Name: ")
   NumOfYears=input("Number of Years: ")
   Salary = input("Salary: ")
   person=Employee(ID, Name, NumOfYears, Salary)
   list.append(person)
for l in list:
   l.printall()

ll.totalSalary()
L1=l.whoislowestTotalSalary()
print(L1)

L2=l.whoishighestTotalSalary()
print(L2)
```

Comment: The class part is missing here.

Comment: heres the full code

Comment: The class declaration is missing here.

Comment: added the class declaration

Comment: Need to be specific with what you want to do with this program, there's a good amount of confusion here in the code.

Comment: im trying to create a class which represents an Employee in an organization.

Comment: There are lot's of missing variables declarations like. From where is ll being access and in sortEmployeesBySalary self.employees variable is missing

Comment: Yes, hence, you cannot have highest and lowest salaries within the class as it is per employee. Maybe just readup a bit more on class and OOPs and do a re-attempt.